# Promoting the left hand side of an assignment operator

Tags: oop, matlab

I've written a Matlab class to handle [dual numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_number) to do [automatic differentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation). For almost all cases this works fine, and the new class is a drop-in replacement for the other numeric classes in most functions (the field 'x' gives the values of the function, and the field d gives the value of the derivative of the function at that point.)

```
>> x = mkdual([1 2 3]);
>> x.^2
ans = 
  Dual

  Properties:
    x: [1 4 9]
    d: [2 4 6]
```

However, it fails when a function pre-allocates an output array, and assigns to the array by indexing into it. For example, the following is a common pattern in Matlab:

```
>> y=zeros(2) // Pre-allocate for speed
y =
     0     0
     0     0
>> x = 1;
>> y(1,:)=x
y =
     1     1
     0     0
```

Unfortunately this fails with my class, since it can't promote the array on the LHS of the assignment operator to a dual number:

```
>> x=mkdual(1);
>> y(2,:)=x
??? The following error occurred converting from Dual to double:
Error using ==> double
Conversion to double from Dual is not possible.
```

Can anyone suggest a fix or a workaround - preferably one which allows automatic promotion of the variable `y` to a `Dual`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example isn't failing because it can't promote `y` to a `Dual`; it's failing because it tries to convert `x` to a double, and can't.

If you wanted to do that, you could add an overloaded `double` method to `Dual` that would do the conversion operation.

I'm guessing that's not what you want though, but rather you want a way of preallocating an array of dummy elements of class `Dual`. To do that you can design the constructor of `Dual` so that it will run with no input arguments, returning a dummy or default `Dual`. Then you can say `y(2,2) = Dual` and you'll have a 2x2 preallocated array of dummy `Dual`s.

Search in the doc for 'Initializing arrays of value objects' for a fuller example.

Alternatively, you could make `y` a cell array instead of an array.

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to automatically promote `y` to a `Dual`, unless you are replacing the variable in its entirety (which defeats the benefits of preallocation).

However, you should be able to preallocate it as a Dual in the first place.  I'm not sure of the syntax, and it may depend on your implementation, but something like:

```
mkdual(zeros(10,10))
```

Alternatively, you can do a lazy pre-allocation by loop backwards.  That is, instead of

```
for ix = 1:100
    y(ix) = mkdual(...)
end
```

Use

```
for ix = 100:-1:1
    y(ix) = mkdual(...)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I suspect I may end up rewriting some of my functions to 'dual versions' that do the relevant pre-allocations as dual numbers. I was hoping that there would be a solution which allowed me to drop in a dual array as an argument, without any changes to the function, but alas there doesn't seem to be. An acceptable 'second best' solution would be to re-jig the functions so that they work with both regular and dual numbers, but I'm not sure how possible that will be.